# Algorithm to return bit status from numeric string?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm converting some code that stores an array of flags in a 64-bit integer to an environment that doesn't have 64 bit integers.  So I need to go from:

```
bool isBitSet(unsigned long long allBits, int bitOrdinal)  // print isBitSet(15908558073855, 44)
```

to:

```
bool isBitSet(string allBits, int bitOrdinal)  // print isBitSet("15908558073855", 44)
```

Of course, in the source environment, the function uses bitwise operations and is very simple. The target environment can use bitwise operations, BUT cannot at any point utilize a long enough integer to represent all the bits.

I'll also need a setFlag, clearFlag.

Anyone had to tackle this before?

Comment: Use char* / BYTE* instead of string and modify the (bitOrdinal % 8)th bit of the (bitOrdinal / 8)th byte.

Comment: Using a hex number instead of decimal will make the job *much* easier.

Comment: Why not `bool isBitSet(uint32_t upperBits, uint32_t lowerBits, int bitOrdinal)`? To put it differently, the design choice you're proposing is going to make your life miserable. So what's driving that design choice?

Comment: @user3386109 The string representation of the number is just what I got, it wasn't a design decision, at least not by me. Being able to get the string to two 32-bit ints would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRansom Indeed, if I could get it to hex, I think it would just look like what user1952500 said.  thanks.

Comment: @user1952500 If I understand correctly, that would work if I could convert the decimal string to hex digits, like what Mark Ransom suggested. But I think that may the tricky part. thanks.

Comment: @leontx, if you pass the 64-bit int as a (char *)&value_in_64bits, it will be the hex representation that you seek.

Comment: @user1952500 if that 64-bit value contains any null bytes you might run into problems treating it as a string. Not to mention needing to append a null byte to the end somehow.

Comment: @MarkRansom the 'string' requirement does not stem from the original problem. The OP does not have a 64-bit integer on his machine. That indicates that the OP initially does computation in integers and then came up with a conversion to string. If that is the problem the way is to use a buffer to store data rather than a string. 
Of course if the OP has a string as a hard requirement then there will be a conversion to raw hex needed. However that is a convoluted route unless the OP is working with extremely large integers and has a library which takes strings of 100 digits and multiplies them.

Comment: And the (char*) mentioned above does not mean anything apart from a representation. It should actually be (void *) with a length parameter. The (char*) does not mean a string and is used in environments where a native (BYTE*) is not present.

Comment: @user1952500 come to think of it a language was never specified. If it's C or C++ your solution would be perfect. If it's another language with similar syntax but no pointers, it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: Agreed completely. Since there was a talk of a 64-bit integer, unsigned long long etc I assumed it was C/C++. But it is not necessary and other languages share these types. You are right.

Comment: To give you a little more context, the language is Monkey-x, a cross-platform compiler. We're creating a browser-based version of one of our mobile games. So our monkey front-end will communicate with the same back-end as our mobile versions do. And the existing JSON returns "someFlags":123454321, which, on this platform, we're persisting those to strings, since we've got no int big enough. I could "cheat" and have the server also send a hex version only used by this client, but since we have several sets of flags that are packaged and sent this way, that's my fallback. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to delegate the bitwise operations to the target platforms instead of doing it within the Monkey-x language. For the html5/browser target, since javascript itself doesn't have 64-bit integers, I was back to the same challenge, except... in javascript, this trail has been blazed, and I was able to use the very nice [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js).

Note that within the BigInteger.js lies the magic I was looking for initially, and if at some point I really need to do it all in Monkey-x, I can convert the needed functions from javascript.

What's a SO answer without some code, so here's the function that utilizes BigInteger.js to determine if a bit is set from a decimal string. Of course the heavy lifting is within the bigInt constructor and ***shiftLeft*** and ***and*** methods:

```
NativeUtil.IsBitSet = function(decimalString, bitIndex)
{
    theBit = bigInt(1).shiftLeft(bitIndex);
    bits = bigInt(decimalString);
    bitsAnded = bits.and(theBit);
    if (bitsAnded.greater(0) )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```